# How to open the video file in my vps?

Tags: video, putty, sftp

I have purchase a vpn service(serverip is a.b.c.d),when  login into   my sftp with putty,i downloaded a video file name movie1 in /root , i want to watch the video file(in server ) played in my pc(client ),input `mplayer  movie1` (mplayer have benn installed in sftp server).
The error message is :

mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing movie1.

vo: couldn't open the X11 display ()!
vo: couldn't open the X11 display ()!
vo: couldn't open the X11 display ()!

How can  in my client   to watch it  to be displayed in my sftp server with mplayer command in putty console ?

Answer (score 1):

In Putty, activate X-Forwarding for your connection.

But don't draw too much hope from this, I doubt your internet connection to your VPS is fast enough to watch movies from remote.

Sorry, I forgot this: Since you're using Windows, you'll need a local X Window Manager. Have a look at MobaXTerm instead of PuTTy.